# Ошибка в сборке gulp-sass

Tags: gulp

не могу запустить сборку gulp, выдает ошибку

```
$ gulp
C:\Users\Алексей\Desktop\LZ\habr\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:22
    throw new Error('`libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?');
    ^

Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
    at getBinding (C:\Users\Алексей\Desktop\LZ\habr\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:22:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Алексей\Desktop\LZ\habr\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:188:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Алексей\Desktop\LZ\habr\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:3:17)
```

обновил node, установил node-sass
как ее лечить?

Comment: [Не помогает?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32666240/4267982)

Comment: нет, не помогло

Comment: Достаточно слабо разбираюсь в подобных ошибках, хотя сам пользуюсь сборкой gulp-sass. Возможно поможет замена Алексей на Alexey + что за libsass - это правильно название ?